# Add text in the center of pentaho ccc donut chart

Tags: pentaho, pie-chart, pentaho-cde

I searched this questions with google and only got some answers for Highcharts or D3 graphs.

this demo is for Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/sJfuA/22/

Also, I found an example here: `http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.com/2014/08/dual-level-pie-chart-in-pentaho-cde.html`, but I couldn't tweak the code to fit my purpose.

## my use case

I create a pie chart with extension point options:

```
slice_innerRadiusEx: 50%
```

which is very similar to this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/make_dream/sugmyyto/, then I'm trying to put numbers in the center of of the pie(see previous demo, in the white area).

## what I want

What I want is almost the same as this chart: http://bl.ocks.org/ckuijjer/6929969, but implement with the code snippet in the second jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done via CCC configuration or extension points.

What people usually do is create a donut chart with a predefined empty space in the center, add a div on top of it and, e.g. using a text component, append whatever text you want in the center of the donut to that div.

The center text isn't really part of the donut, it's added by a separate component. Then it's a matter of crafting your CSS carefully to align the text with the center of the donut and not allow it to overflow its container.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion, try to put a text in the center of the donut, but without luck. Can you try that at here: http://jsfiddle.net/make_dream/sugmyyto/

Comment: Attach a div on top of the chart div element; with CSS make it float over the chart and align it. Sorry, can't spend time doing that work for you.